# Expected end of statement error

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, ms-access-2007

This is my code:

```
MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "pat/detail.asp?Patient_Id=<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("Patient_Id").Value)%>"
```

I get this error:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'
>
> Expected end of statement
>
> /mp/patTest.asp, line 42

The browser does not show anything. I want to pass the Patient_Id to detail.asp page and the value of Patient_Id is fetched from database. So I feel there is syntax error while passing those values

Comment: This the Error..
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'

Expected end of statement

/mp/patTest.asp, line 42

MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "pat/detail.asp?Patient_Id=<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("Patient_Id").Value)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

Comment: browser does not show any thing. I want to pass the `Patient_Id` to `detail.asp` page and the value of `Patient_Id` is fetched from database. So  i feel there is syntax error while passing that values

Comment: You should escape somehow the quotes around `Patient_Id` (not sure how it's done in VB).

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the following code already surrounded by `<% %>`?

```
MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "pat/detail.asp?Patient_Id=<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("Patient_Id").Value)%>"
```

If so, it should be:

```
<%
    MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "pat/detail.asp?Patient_Id=" & _
        Recordset1.Fields.Item("Patient_Id").Value

%>
```

Comment: I have to pass value the `Patient_Id` to detail.asp and which i am fetching the data using `Recordset1.Fields.Item("Patient_Id").Value`

Comment: I understand that; did you try either of our suggestions?  If they don't work, post your full code please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "pat/detail.asp?Patient_Id=" & Recordset1.Fields.Item("Patient_Id").Value)
```

Comment: Actually I want to pass `Patient_Id` value to `detail.asp` through URL. And by trying your code. the value is not pass to `detail.asp`. Not worked for me